# How to creating a template class that abstracts the data types?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, stdvector

I am writing a set of algorithms to create a simple unit test framework. The class titled `UnitTest` is instantiated with a character string titled `strng` that describes the test being conducted.  The data types are also passed at object instantiation, which allows the compiler to know what data types are being passed.  The `main.cpp` file and `unit_test.hpp` file are shown below

```
// main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include "unit_test.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> array_one = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<float> array_two = {0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99};

    std::string c ("Vector Test");
    UnitTest<int, float> q(c);
    double unc = 0.1;
    q.vectors_are_close(array_two, array_four, unc);
    return 0;
}

// unit_test.hpp file
#ifndef unit_test_hpp
#define unit_test_hpp
#endif /* unit_test_hpp */
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <class type1, class type2> class UnitTest
{
public:
    unsigned long remain;
    std::string str;
    UnitTest(std::string strng) {
        str = strng;
        remain = 50 - str.length();
    };
    void vectors_are_close(std::vector<type1>& i, std::vector<type2>& j, double k);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    void is_close(type1& i, type2& j, double k);
};

template <class type1, class type2> void UnitTest<type1, type2>::
vectors_are_close(std::vector<type1>& i, std::vector<type2>& j, double k)
{
    if (i.size() != j.size()) 
    {
        std::cout << str + std::string(remain, '.') +
            std::string("FAILED") << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        try
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < i.size(); a++) {
                is_close(i[a], j[a], k);
            }
            std::cout << str + std::string(remain, '.') +
                std::string("PASSED") << std::endl;
        }
        catch (const char* msg)
        {
            std::cout << str + std::string(remain, '.') +
                std::string("FAILED") << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

template <class type1, class type2> void UnitTest<type1, type2>::
is_close(type1& i, type2& j, double k)
{
    double percent_diff = abs((j - i) / ((i + j) / 2.0));
    if (percent_diff > k)
    {
        throw "Number not in Tolerance";
    }
}
```

The member function which shown above iterates through the vector containers to ensure that the data in each induce matches the second vector within a certain tolerance.  While the code as written works just fine, it requires the user to re-instantiate the class every time they want to conduct a unit test with a different data type.

In this case, the class is instantiated with `UnitTest<int, float>`. But in another instance, it may be instantiated with `UnitTest<float, double>`.

There is nothing wrong with this approach, but it would seem more elegant to just instantiate the class once with something like `UnitTest<>` and just have the `vectors_are_close()` function accept the different data types.  Is there some way to facilitate this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you do not want to instantiate the class with template arguments but simply with class name `UnitTest` and want to pass different instances of member functions, as per the different `type1`s and `type2`s.

If so, you don't need a template class instead, **templated member functions**:

```
class UnitTest 
{
private:
    std::string str;
    unsigned long remain;
public:
    UnitTest(const std::string& strng)
        : str{ strng },
          remain{ 50 - str.size() }
    {}

    template <class type1, class type2>
    void vectors_are_close(const std::vector<type1> &i, const std::vector<type2> &j, double k)
    {
       // code
    }
private:
    template <class type1, class type2>
    void is_close(type1 i, type2 j, double k)
    {
      // code
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> array_one{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<float> array_two{ 0.99f, 1.99f, 2.99f, 3.99f };
    std::vector<double> array_three{ 0.99, 1.99, 2.99, 3.99 };
    double unc = 0.1;

    UnitTest q{ std::string{"Vector Test"} }; // non-templated class
    // call different types of args to same UnitTest obj
    q.vectors_are_close(array_one, array_two, unc);
    q.vectors_are_close(array_one, array_three, unc);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Note**: In case, you want to instantiate the member functions only for integers and floats(or any special group of types), use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) along with them.

For instance, following `is_oky_types` traits will allow you to instantiate the member functions for only the arithmetic types which are valid for the function body.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Type>
using is_oky_type = std::conjunction<
    std::is_arithmetic<Type>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, bool>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char16_t>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, char32_t>>,
    std::negation<std::is_same<Type, wchar_t>> >;

template<typename T, typename U>
using is_oky_types = std::conjunction<is_oky_type<T>, is_oky_type<U>>;
```

and in the member functions:

```
template <
    class type1,
    class type2,
    std::enable_if_t<is_oky_types<type1, type2>::value>* = nullptr
>
void  vectors_are_close(const std::vector<type1> &i, const std::vector<type2> &j, double k)
{
    // code...
}

template <class type1, class type2>
void is_close(
    type1 i,
    type2 j,
    double k,
    std::enable_if_t<is_oky_types<type1, type2>::value>* = nullptr)
{
    // code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I didn't think you could instantiate a template function in a non-template class, but I now see that was because I was not declaring the class types in the function, and only did that in the prototype.  Shortly I will be asking another related question.